# Compile MATLAB bindings for OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I am trying to compile the MATLAB bindings for OpenCV 3.0, i.e. the current build from Github. I keep getting the following errors:

```
CMake Error at /opencv/modules/matlab/compile.cmake:47 (message):
  Failed to compile createCalibrateDebevec:
  /opencv/build/modules/matlab/src/createCalibrateDebevec.cpp:
  In function ‘void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)’:

  /opencv/build/modules/matlab/src/createCalibrateDebevec.cpp:46:3:
  error: ‘Ptr_CalibrateDebevec’ was not declared in this scope
```

This occurs for multiple files. I found this [thread](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3445), which discusses a couple of remedies, viz. adding some typedefs to the bridge.hpp file, but that results in even more errors while compiling. I also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430471/error-while-compiling-linking-opencv-matlab-source-files) which suggested removing the problematic .cpp files and compiling. This resulted in error-free compilation followed by the usual make install. However, calling any OpenCV function from inside MATLAB now results in errors such as:

```
If = cv.dft(I, 'flags', cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
Error using dft
cv::exception caught:
/home/xxx/opencv-master/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp:1760: error: (-215)
type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_64FC2
in function dft
```

Another error example:

```
im_denoise = cv.fastNlMeansDenoising(im_noise, 18);
Error using fastNlMeansDenoising
cv::exception caught:
/home/xxx/opencv-master/modules/photo/src/fast_nlmeans_denoising_invoker.hpp:146:
error: (-215) almost_dist2weight_[0] == fixed_point_mult_ in function
FastNlMeansDenoisingInvoker
```

Any help on how to resolve these issues is much appreciated!

Comment: @AruniRC - you started a bounty because "this question has not recieved enough attention" - but you do not provide any feedback regarding answers and proposals you get here... This is not the right way to get attention.

Comment: I was able to compile and link everything, without any errors. I just made sure that I had the same architecture for each of the libraries/sdks used while compiling. For example, if your matlab is 64bit then make sure you have 64bit Compiler selected in CMake and also a 64bit Python is found. However, somehow the matlab files are not accompanied by their mex files. I can see all the .cpp files generated, however no compiled mex after compiling and installing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `'cv::exception caught'` errors you get: it seems like `cv` is expecting the input image to be of floating point type (either `single` or `double`, `'CV_32FC1'` or `'CV_64FC1'` respectively).
Try converting your input image `I` or `im_noise` to floating point using `im2single` or `im2double` and see if these errors recurr.

Comment: This threw new errors. Guess I'll just wait for the MATLAB bindings to be released along with the next official release of OpenCV. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [this tutorial](http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/compiling-opencv-30-with-matlab-support.html) regarding compiling matlab mex for the latest OpenCV 3.0 dev.

It also contains precompiled binaries for the OpenCV matlab as well as C++